# Calling a function by clicking an image

Tags: html, image, function, onclick, popup

I found a function to centre a pop-up on screen:

```
function PopupCenter(url, title, w, h) {
    // Fixes dual-screen position                         Most browsers      Firefox
    var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : window.screenX;
    var dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : window.screenY;

    var width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;
    var height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;

    var left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft;
    var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop;
    var newWindow = window.open(url, title, 'scrollbars=yes, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);

    // Puts focus on the newWindow
    if (window.focus) {
        newWindow.focus();
    }
}
```

But when I'm trying to call it by pressing an image, nothing happens, I'm not even getting a "klick me" mouse.

```
<img src="https://rainbowcats.se/img/btn-makeown.gif" height ="auto" width ="80%"alt="Skapa din egen minnessida" onclick= "PopupCenter('https://upload.rainbowcats.se','xtf','900','500');">
```

The function is loaded in the head, the other in the body ..

Anybody got any suggestions?

Comment: Have you used external js?

Comment: These codes should work. perhaps there is a mistake in implementation of function in html codes.

Comment: Are you sure your function is called at all (test with alert)? And, by the way, to show a "click me mouse", add `style="cursor: pointer"`

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: These codes are all in the HTML page, strangely has the page begun to show the first code, the function..

Answer (score 1):

I'm ashamed of my self.

I forgot the most important thing, I forgot to set the function inside a JavaScript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
(Function)
    </Script>
```

Sometimes it's the easiest things that slips the mind..